# Functions passed to react component children don't receive function context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, undefined, react-props

I am getting stuck while using react, wherein, I am passing a function from a parent component to multiple children components. That function calls other functions that also reside within the parent component.

The children components do successfully start the function, but unfortunately, the function fails because it seems to not have the same context from within the children's elements, eg. it begins calling the other functions stored within the parent element, and receives undefined. This is strange because the error is coming from the parent component file, not the child component file.

I was not sure whether to pass all the functions to the children elements, which feels rather bulky, and also feels like I would still be missing important function context.

I have tested running the same function on the parent component and it has no issues, almost like the function context from the parent component is not passed to the child component, only the function itself.

Is that correct?

Here is an example where the child component has a button to click that would run the function that was passed from the parent component and includes running other functions from within the parent component, updating state and making changes, etc.

Parent element:

```
class Content extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "React",
      toggle: true,
      ...
    };
  }
  toggleComponent(name) {
      this.toggling(name); // THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS ON THE CHILD ELEMENT, undefined.
  }
  toggling(name) {
      does some stuff...
  }

  render() {
   return (
    <Comp toggleComponent={this.toggleComponent}/>
   )
  }
```

Child element:

```
class Demo1 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "React"
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <div className="button" onClick={() => this.props.toggleComponent('theCompName')}>Continue</div>
    )
```

Let me know what can be done to pass the additional context to the children components or if there is a better way to do this.

Thanks, you are all very smart.

Comment: have you tried using the arrow syntax to define your methods?

Comment: Or,  `this.toggleComponent.bind(this)` in the constructor

Comment: Sorry, `this.toggleComponent = this.toggleComponent.bind(this)`

Comment: @WillD I had not tried that, what is the difference in functionality by defining the functions that way?

Comment: "An arrow function does not have its own `this`. The this value of the enclosing lexical scope is used" from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your constructor for your `Content` class, try binding your toggleComponent function to the class using `.bind()`:

```js
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "React",
      toggle: true,
      ...
    };

    this.toggleComponent = this.toggleComponent.bind(this);
  }
```

Class methods are not "bound" to the class by default. This means that your `this` keyword in `toggleComponent` does not refer to the `Content` class until you specify it using `.bind()`.

Hope this helps!

More info can be found here: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing this with me, I had seen a lot about .bind while I was troubleshooting but never thought it would be the culprit for this. Why would this allow the function to run when executed from the parent? I will have to do more research. Thanks for the link as well.

Comment: The function runs even without .bind(). What .bind() does is make the `this` in `this.toggling(name)` actually refer to the `Content` class instead of nothing, so you can call the other member function that you defined (`toggling`). And no problem, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Use arrow syntax in the parent component's functions. That will allow the functions in the parent component to execute in the parent component's context. Otherwise you'll have to do a bunch of binding(this) crap to make that work properly.

Comment: `bind` is actually a nice solution, problem with arrow function here you will need to use on all the child components, with bind you just do it to the parent and your done.   And of course using an arrow function loses `this`, ok if your using scope, but as the OP is using the class based React, `this` might be useful to keep..